# How to notify ListModel that ArrayList have changed

Tags: java, jlist

I would like to notify `ListModel` that a certain `ArrayList` have been modified.

My `ArrayList` is automatically updated after I create every person by:

```
new Person(...);
```

It is achieved as I add every person to  `ArrayList`   at the end of `Person` constructor.
I would like to `ListModel` listen to any changes in that `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` is part of a `HashMap<Class, ArrayList>` where all instances of every class are stored.

How to notify `ListModel` that the `ArrayList` have been changed?

Notice: I don't mean: how to make `ListModel` notify the `Jlist`.

Comment: Please try to improve this question by showing us your best good faith attempt and by asking a much more specific question over just what confuses you. So please, give it a try

Comment: Add the Person instance to the ListModel as well.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc This causes code duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [ObservableList](http://doc.formdev.com/beansbinding/org/jdesktop/observablecollections/ObservableList.html) instead of `ArrayList` and register a `ObservableListListener` on your `ListModel`

or for simplicty sake, use a [Property Change Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html)

Comment: Is there any drawback of using `ObservableList` towards `ArrayList`. Please see my OP edit.

Comment: No, `ObservableList` implements the `List` interface. This is a perfect example of where it is `good to program to the interface and not to the implementation.` So your program wont even notice the difference. The only possible drawback might be the need for an external library.